# Black screen in a SharpDx toolkit (DirectX) game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sharpdx

I'm writing a SharpDx(directX) Windows Phone 8 game where everything worked until now. When I changed the size of the DrawingSurface, the phone screen during debugging was only black. Immediately I have everything undone and uninstalled the app, then the screen was still black. Now I have checked with breakpoints where the program stops working, at the end came out that, the phone every line passes through to the line

`TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();`.

After that nothing happens, there is also no warning or anything. However, when I start the app without debugging, I can easily operate the app.

Has anyone an idea?

Here is a Screenshot:

[image: Here is a Screenshot![enter image description here]![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcsoL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the solution to my problem.

Solution(Very simple):

> The DrawingSurface doesn't work because an Microsoft Advertising SDK has disturbed it.

Comment: When I press on the hook there comes this message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". In 2 days I will press it.